# How do I configure my Nginx server to work with a React app in a subfolder?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to deploy a React application in a subfolder on my Nginx server.

The location of this React app is structured like: www.example.com/reactApp.

I tried to set up my current nginx.conf like so:

```
server {
    ..other configs..

    location /reactApp {
        root /var/www;
        index reactApp/index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }  

    ..other configs..
}
```

This has not worked. What do I need to change to fix my subfolder routing?

Comment: Can you set the basename on the react router to `/reactApp`? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The last component of the `try_files` statement should be a URI.  Assuming that your `index.html` file is located under the `/var/www/reactApp` subfolder, you should use:

```
location /reactApp {
    root /var/www;
    index  index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /reactApp/index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.