# How do I configure my Nginx server to work with create-react app in a subfolder?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, subdirectory, nginx-config

I'm using the create-react app template with react router and I want to deploy my app on a subfolder using nginx.

My nginx.conf file looks like this. (I'm using the nginx-alpine docker image)

```
events { }
http {

server {
    listen 80;
    # You would want to make a separate file with its own server block for each virtual domain
    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    location /procejts/myproject/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /procejts/myproject/index.html;
    }

 }
}
```

However I'm getting an empty page when I go to mydomain.com/procejts/myproject

I have tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836667/how-do-i-configure-my-nginx-server-to-work-with-a-react-app-in-a-subfolder) but it is giving me a 500 error “rewrite or internal redirection cycle”. I changed the

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /procejts/myproject/index.html;
```

To

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

and I start to get 404 not found.